# entity framework extended batch delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I use entity framework 6 extended batch delete, it throw some error "Sequence contains more than one element".
This is the stack trace:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +2614213
EntityFramework.Mapping.MetadataMappingProvider.GetEntityMap(Type type, ObjectContext objectContext) +546
EntityFramework.Mapping.MetadataMappingProvider.GetEntityMap(ObjectQuery query) +54
EntityFramework.Mapping.MappingResolver.GetEntityMap(ObjectQuery query) +85
EntityFramework.Extensions.BatchExtensions.Delete(IQueryable`1 source) +99
Vcs.Data.RepositoryBase`1.Delete(Expression`1 where) in d:\Work2014\Website\Vcs.Data\Infrastructure\RepositoryBase.cs:50
Vcs.Service.LogService.Clear() in d:\Work2014\Website\Vcs.Service\Logs\LogService.cs:55
Vcs.Web.Areas.SysAdmin.Controllers.SiteLogController.Clear() in d:\Work2014\Website\Vcs.Web\Areas\SysAdmin\Controllers\SiteLogController.cs:31
lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
```

I want to clear some rows.

```
this.dbSet.Where(where).Delete();
```

Comment: Just a wild guess, does that entity have a composite key? Maybe EFX doesn't support composite keys. At any rate, it looks like this entity has more than one *something* where EFX was only expecting one *something*.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this...

```
this.dbSet.Where(row => row.Id == 15).Delete();
```